# who was the real-life model for Artem Ivanoff in Detroit: Become Human

Tags: character-identification, video-games, detroit-become-human

Trying to find out who is the model of the Russian president Artem Ivanoff in the video game Detroit: Become Human

[image]

?

Comment: I'm seeing quite a list of "Character Likeness" in the credits: https://www.igdb.com/games/detroit-become-human--1/credits But the site doesn't have a picture for each of them, and it's not even guaranteed to find a picture, nor the guy himself.

Comment: @Clockwork thank you, it is a start